# How to place app bar in Flutter main screen because showing white bar over there

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

So I am using google apps on screen and my appbar seems to be missing. I have tried everything but does not seem to work. I have uploaded the picture and code for better clarification. I want some text to be written at the top and dashboard/appbar button at the place when there is an arrow pointing left.

```dart
  return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          // elevation: 0,
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.red),
            onPressed: () {
              // passing this to our root
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
      
          ),
      drawer: MyDrawer(),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          GoogleMap(
            mapType: MapType.normal,
            myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
            initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
            onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
              _google_map_controller.complete(controller);
              new_google_map_controller_for_saving = controller;
            },
          ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,` and set the appbar color to transparent.

```dart
return Scaffold(
  extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
  appBar: AppBar(
      elevation: 0,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
```